# Refreshing a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very simple requirement where I need a screen divided into two pieces where the first half is used to input data and the other is to display results based on the input (very similar to frames in browsers). the first half will remain static and will never change.

Is there a way to do it without using fragments and just by using layouts ?

Comment: You can use just layouts of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by m0skit0 just divide the screen by two with a layout and put the static part on one side and for example a WebView on the other side that you update with the content you want to show (or any other view of course).

Comment: Being a newbie, just have a quick question. Do i need to use two activities to be able to refresh the dynamic part? Or I can just have one activity and on some event, I can update the the dynamic part without touching the static one.

Comment: sure you can put this in one activity. Most Activities are reacting to user interaction by changing something. So you can for example use the onClick(View v) to change the content of the view that you get with findViewById